# Static HTML Snapshot in Django for SEO

Tags: ajax, django, seo, mustache, django-rest-framework

We make use of ajax in our Django web app pretty extensively. It's not a one page design but in most cases we just serve a HTML skeleton with Django's build in template engine and load most of the content with JavaScript async.

I read this article by google "[Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)". They suggest creating HTML snapshots for better search engine visibility.

We are using the [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) and [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) for templates.

Is there a straight forward way to generate static html pages (HTML snapshots) with this setup?

Comment: what did you end up doing? I'm currently in your same position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up writing a custom jquery library called pjaxr inspired by [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). Find more about it here:

https://github.com/iekadou/django-pjaxr

We also wrote a Django specific implementation:

https://github.com/iekadou/django-pjaxr

Pjaxr uses pushState which is seo friendly. For browsers that don't support pushState pjaxr fully degrades to normal static html.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into Selenium. You can use it to generate your page in the context of a browser (e.g., including things like Ajax). It's designed to be a testing tool, but that shouldn't matter.